# How to compile atl files using maven

Tags: maven

I have an ATL projects and i need to compile it using maven.

Is it possible to compile with maven other files rather than java?

Does anyone experienced before compiling atl files using maven?

Answer (score 0):

I would you should take a look into the [maven-nar-plugin](http://duns.github.com/maven-nar-plugin/) which is designed to compile C++ code etc. but unfortunately this plugin is not available via Maven Central. Furthermore it currently exists only in a SNAPSHOT version.
Also exists a [maven-native-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/maven-native/native-maven-plugin/) which might be worth a look as well.